# Specific russian character is not shown correctly.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a specific russian character that does not get shown correctly on my website..

The website consists of MVC 5.2.3.0 on ASP.NET version 4.5.2. The issue happens both on test server and on local iis express.. BUT This issue only happens when "debug" is set to false or removed in web.config.

the problem is that the capital "P" in russian gets transformed into a "?". Only that character. The rest is fine.

If i insert "Расширенный поиск" in any cshtml file and get the page shown in a browser it looks like: "� асширенный поиск".

If I get the same text through ajax call(non razor) and insert it in the page, it looks fine.

Anyone knowing why and how to fix it ?

Comment: seems character encoding problem. Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516567/razor-view-character-rendered-as-%C3%82) helps.

Comment: Tried that fix but unfortunately no dice. Even tried adding a <globalization> to the web.config to try and force utf-8. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up replacing that capital "P" with a normal P since they looked the same and that did the trick.